# Android smooth game loop

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have problems with smooth scrolling in OpenGL (testing on SGS2 and ACE) 
I created simple applications - only fixed speed horizontal scrolling of images, or only one image (player) moving by accelerator, 
but it's movement is not smooth :-( 
I tried many various of code but no satisfaction...

first I tried work with **GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY** and I put all code to onDrawFrame:

```
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) 
    {
      updateGame(gl, 0.017f);
      drawGame(gl); 
    }
```

this is the simplest and absolute smooth!! - but it's dependent on hardware speed (= useless)

```
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) 
    { 
      frameTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();        
      elapsedTime = (frameTime - lastTime) / 1000; 
      updateGame(gl, elapsedTime);
      drawGame(gl); 
      lastTime = frameTime; 
    }
```

this is the best of all but it's not as smooth as the previous, sometimes flick
second I tried **GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY**, in onDrawFrame i have only drawing objects and this code in separate Thread:

```
   while (true) 
   {
     updateGame(renderer, 0.017f);
     mGLSurfaceView.requestRender();
     next_game_tick += SKIP_TICKS;
     sleep_time = next_game_tick - System.currentTimeMillis();
     if (sleep_time >= 0) 
     {
       try 
       {
          Thread.sleep(sleep_time);
       } 
       catch (Exception e) {}
       }
       else 
       {
         Log.d("running behind: ", String.valueOf(sleep_time));
       }
     }
```

this is not smooth and it's not problem with "running behind"
My objective is smooth image movement like in first code example above.

Possible error is somewhere else then I looking. Please, Can somebody help me with this?
 
Is better use RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY or RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY?

Thank you.

Comment: 'moving by accelerator'  Accelerometers give you back jumpy data.  Could that be your problem?  Try smoothing out the movement by doing something like "someLoc += (newLoc - someLoc) * .1f;"

Comment: hello, if i try to disable accelerometer and only simple move images by constant value it sporadic flick too (trying it with RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY now)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I was fighting with the exact same issue for several days. The loop looks smooth without any Android time reference, but as soon it includes any type of “time sync” , external factors out of the android development control introduce serious discontinuities to the final result.

Basically, these factors are:

- eglSwapInterval is not implemented in Android, so is difficult to know the moment when the hardware expose the final draw in the screen (hardware screen sync)
- Thread.sleep is not precise. The Thread may sleep more or less than requested.
- SystemClock.uptimeMillis()System.nanoTime(), System.currentTimeMillis() and other timing related measurement are not accurate (its precise).

The issue is independent of the drawing technology (drawing, openGL 1.0/1.1 and 2.0) and the game loop method (fixed time step, interpolation, variable time step).
Like you, I was trying Thread.sleep, crazy interpolations, timers, etc. Doesn’t matter what you will do, we don’t have control over this factors.

According with many Q&A on this site, the basic rules to produce smooth continuous animations are:

- Reduce at the minimum the GC by removing all dynamic memory request.
- Render frames as fast the hardware can process them  (40 to 60fps is ok in most android devices).
- Use fixed time steps with interpolation or variable time steps.
- Optimize the update physics and draw routines to be execute in relative constant time without high peaks variance.

For sure, you made a lot of previous work before post this question by optimizing your updateGame() and drawGame()  (without appreciable GC and relative constant execution time)  in order to get a smooth animation in your main loop as you mention: “simple and absolute smooth”.

Your particular case with variable stepTime and no special requirements to be in perfect sync with realTime events (like music), the solution is simple: “smooth the step Time variable”.
The solution works with other game loop schemes (fixed time step with variable rendering) and is easy to port the concept (smooth the amount of displacement produced by the updateGame and the real time clock across several frames.)

```
    // avoid GC in your threads. declare nonprimitive variables out of onDraw
    float smoothedDeltaRealTime_ms=17.5f; // initial value, Optionally you can save the new computed value (will change with each hardware) in Preferences to optimize the first drawing frames 
    float movAverageDeltaTime_ms=smoothedDeltaRealTime_ms; // mov Average start with default value
    long lastRealTimeMeasurement_ms; // temporal storage for last time measurement

    // smooth constant elements to play with
    static final float movAveragePeriod=40; // #frames involved in average calc (suggested values 5-100)
    static final float smoothFactor=0.1f; // adjusting ratio (suggested values 0.01-0.5)

    // sample with opengl. Works with canvas drawing: public void OnDraw(Canvas c)   
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl){       
        updateGame(gl, smoothedDeltaRealTime_ms); // divide 1000 if your UpdateGame routine is waiting seconds instead mili-seconds.
        drawGame(gl);  

        // Moving average calc
        long currTimePick_ms=SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        float realTimeElapsed_ms;
        if (lastRealTimeMeasurement_ms>0){
        realTimeElapsed_ms=(currTimePick_ms - lastRealTimeMeasurement_ms);
        } else {
                 realTimeElapsed_ms=smoothedDeltaRealTime_ms; // just the first time
        }
        movAverageDeltaTime_ms=(realTimeElapsed_ms + movAverageDeltaTime_ms*(movAveragePeriod-1))/movAveragePeriod;

         // Calc a better aproximation for smooth stepTime
        smoothedDeltaRealTime_ms=smoothedDeltaRealTime_ms +(movAverageDeltaTime_ms - smoothedDeltaRealTime_ms)* smoothFactor;

        lastRealTimeMeasurement_ms=currTimePick_ms;
    }

    // Optional: check if the smoothedDeltaRealTIme_ms is too different from original and save it in Permanent preferences for further use.
```

For a fixed time step scheme, an intermetiate updateGame can be implemented to improve the results:

```
float totalVirtualRealTime_ms=0;
float speedAdjustments_ms=0; // to introduce a virtual Time for the animation (reduce or increase animation speed)
float totalAnimationTime_ms=0;
float fixedStepAnimation_ms=20; // 20ms for a 50FPS descriptive animation
int currVirtualAnimationFrame=0; // useful if the updateGameFixedStep routine ask for a frame number

private void updateGame(){
    totalVirtualRealTime_ms+=smoothedDeltaRealTime_ms + speedAdjustments_ms;

    while (totalVirtualRealTime_ms> totalAnimationTime_ms){
        totalAnimationTime_ms+=fixedStepAnimation_ms;
        currVirtualAnimationFrame++;
        // original updateGame with fixed step                
        updateGameFixedStep(currVirtualAnimationFrame);
    }


    float interpolationRatio=(totalAnimationTime_ms-totalVirtualRealTime_ms)/fixedStepAnimation_ms;
    Interpolation(interpolationRatio);
}
```

Tested with canvas and openGlES10 drawing with the following devices: SG SII (57 FPS), SG Note(57 FPS) , SG tab(60 FPS), unbranded Android 2.3 (43 FPS) slow emulator running on Windows XP(8 FPS). The test platform draws around 45 objects + 1 huge background (texture from 70MP source image) moving along a path specified in real physics parameters (km/h and  G’s), without spikes or flick between several devices (well, 8 FPS on the emulator doesn’t look good, but its flow at constant speed as expected)

Check The graphs for how android report the time. Some times Android report a large delta time and just the next loop it's small than average, meaning an offset on the reading of realTime value.

[image]

with more detail:
[image]

[How to limit framerate when using Android's GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772693/how-to-limit-framerate-when-using-androids-glsurfaceview-rendermode-continuousl)

[System.currentTimeMillis vs System.nanoTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351565/system-currenttimemillis-vs-system-nanotime)

[Does the method System.currentTimeMillis() really return the current time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902368/does-the-method-system-currenttimemillis-really-return-the-current-time)

Comment: Hi again, 
so, there must be an error in this example - value of smoothTimeStep is repeatedly increased, but if I try "smoothTimeStep=gameTimeElapsed*smoothFactor+(temp-gameTimeElapsed)" - it's look nice :-) 

Now it's much better, but sometimes flick too (not as often) - I logged smoothTimeStep and here it's values: 0.021 0.021 0.021 ........ 0.06 0.095 0.03 0.008 0.007 0.005 0.021 0.021 
Maybe this is problem only on samsung HW (tested on SGS2), I will try on another device.

Comment: You are right.In the process of simplified and adapt my code manually for you I type the wrong formula as you quote. (fixed and tested in real devices now). My case requires synchronism with music on background (audio an animation runs in sync). I edit the answer to fit your requirements on a better way without the music real time requirement on mind.  (moving average). Try this code, and if you feel happy, I suggest edit the title for a more general question like “Android smooth game loop”. The issue (your question) and the solution are not related with the draw technology(canvas or openGL).

Comment: What do you think about using the android Timer class? I've been using it and the animation seems good.

Comment: @javqui, Hi, I've been having problems with my Android Java game loop for a really long time, could you take a look at my open question if you get a chance please?  Thanks : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38512936/android-understanding-ondrawframe-fps-and-vsync-opengl-es-2-0?noredirect=1#comment64502253_38512936

Comment: Just came across this solution and it works astonishingly well. Great Idea!!