# Show frames in a stable speed.(OpenGL ES 2.0 for android ndk)

Tags: android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0, frame-rate

I've tried to use openGL with ndk.
Some devices seem to show frames very slowly.
I'd like to show frames stably.

If a device is too fast, I can set a limit like this code.

[How to limit framerate when using Android's GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772693/how-to-limit-framerate-when-using-androids-glsurfaceview-rendermode-continuousl)

On the contrary, If it's too slow, what should I do?
I mean, how can I control fps on Android's GLSurfaceView?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should make your logic agnostic of the frame rate. For example all your animations should be computed based on a frame_delta_time. This delta_time is computed using the average time it took to render the last frames (or the last one).

Check this: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13008/how-to-get-and-use-delta-time

There are some solutions to limit your frame rate, but my advice is to make your logic frame rate agnostics first, then think about limiting the frame rate: [How to limit framerate when using Android's GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772693/how-to-limit-framerate-when-using-androids-glsurfaceview-rendermode-continuousl)